# Custom NSLevelIndicator doesn't show assigned values

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nstextfield, nslevelindicator

I have created a custom `NSLevelIndicator` which can display a string value within it. Below is the code for it. I tested this in a storyboard OSX app and it works well.

[image]

```
import Cocoa

class CustomLevelIndicator: NSLevelIndicator {

    var text: String!

    private var textField: NSTextField!

    override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.drawRect(dirtyRect)
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        textField = NSTextField()
        textField.stringValue = text
        textField.bezeled = false
        textField.drawsBackground = false
        textField.editable = false
        textField.selectable = false
        textField.textColor = NSColor.blackColor()
        textField.font = NSFont.systemFontOfSize(12)
        textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(textField, positioned: .Above, relativeTo: nil)

        let xCenterConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: textField, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        let yCenterConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: textField, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        addConstraints([xCenterConstraint, yCenterConstraint])
    }
}
```

Now I'm trying to use the same control in a menu bar app. Here's the view layout of it.

[image]

The code of the menu object.

```
class ProgressMenuController: NSObject {

    @IBOutlet weak var menu: NSMenu!
    @IBOutlet weak var progressView: ProgressView!

    let menuItem = NSStatusBar.systemStatusBar().statusItemWithLength(NSVariableStatusItemLength)

    var progressMenuItem: NSMenuItem!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        menuItem.menu = menu
        menuItem.image = NSImage(named: "icon")

        progressMenuItem = menu.itemWithTitle("Progress")
        progressMenuItem.view = progressView

        progressView.update(42)
    }

    @IBAction func quitClicked(sender: NSMenuItem) {
        NSApplication.sharedApplication().terminate(self)
    }
}
```

The code for the view that has the level indicator.

```
import Cocoa

class ProgressView: NSView {

    @IBOutlet weak var progressIndicator: CustomLevelIndicator!

    func update(value: Double) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.progressIndicator.doubleValue = value
            self.progressIndicator.text = "\(value)%"
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is the text in custom level indicator doesn't show up. And the level indicator has some sort of a dark overlay.

[image]

I can't figure out why this is happening. In my actual app, the values for this indicator is updated periodically via a network request that executes in a background thread. That's why I update the UI in the main thread specifically in the `update()` function. I took the code inside the closure and put it outside just to test, still it doesn't work. Note that the problem is with assigning the value for the `text` property and not the `doubleValue` as you can see the level indicator's value is updated properly but not the text. I'm kinda stumped now.

Any help is appreciated. I [uploaded](https://www.dropbox.com/s/g0m8qtv62pq8jcd/TooltipTest.zip?dl=0) a demo project here as well.

Answer (score 0):

Override the property doubleValue in CustomLevelIndicator. In the setter you set text and textField.stringValue.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but there is no method called `setDoubleValue`. I think that was in Objective-C. In Swift it's just a property called `doubleValue`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still using Objective-C. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here seems like it might be your code is lacking an `IBOutlet` for the `NSTextField`. You could probably fix the issue by adding one that overlays your `NSLevelIndicator` and associating it. I didn't try your code, however, doing something as simple as the following should give you a better idea of what to do:

```
import Cocoa

class ProgressView: NSView {

    @IBOutlet weak var progressIndicator: CustomLevelIndicator!
    @IBOutlet weak var textValue: NSTextField!

    func update(value: Double) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.progressIndicator.doubleValue = value
            self.textValue.stringValue = "\(value)%"
        }
    }
}
```

Then just add the NSTextField on top of the NSLevelIndicator and reference ProgressView with textValue in IB; you should be in business from there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I'm not adding the `NSTextField` from the interface builder. I'm adding it programmatically. So it's impossible to add an `IBOutlet`.

Comment: You've obviously added the other elements via IB, so it's unclear why there would be an issue there.